# Returning a variable from a function in an imported module

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm setting up a Framework7 project with webpack, and I want a module for database requests using Firebase. The function from the imported module runs, but the requested array is never returned/the promise doesn't resolve. What am I doing wrong?

I suspect that I'm either doing something wrong when importing the module itself, or I'm not resolving the promise properly. I've tried and failed with both *return* and *resolve* in the getAllRestaurants function in the module. I've tried waiting for the response from the database call with *async/await*, *.then()* and even with a *setTimout*. I've also tried just saying *let array = database.getAllRestaurants()*.

**database.js(module)**

```
  // Initialize Firebase
  import firebase from 'firebase'
  import config from '../config';
  const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
  const db = firebase.firestore(firebaseApp);

//getting array form database

export function getAllRestaurants(){
    //defining db route omitted
    let array = [];
    route.get().then(function(querySnapshot){
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach(function(document){
            array.push(document.data());
        });
        return array; //Have tried with only return and with only resolve
    })
    .resolve(array)  //Have tried with only return and with only resolve
    .catch(function(error){
        console.error('error i firebase getallrestaurants: ', error);
    });
}
//The function getAllRestaurants works and gets the array just fine, so the error is in returning it to the function caller
```

**app.js (main)**

```
//importing my module
import * as database from './database';

//trying to return an array from a function in the module
let array = database.getAllRestaurants(); //returns undefined

//another attempt at getting the same array, .then never executes
database.getAllRestaurants().then((array =>{
  //do stuff
}));
```

I expected the code in app.js to get an array from the function, but it only gets 'undefined'

Comment: Because `getAllRestaurants()` is based on an *asynchronous* operation (the database operation), you *cannot* simply return a value from it. You can however return a Promise, and have the client code expect that.

Comment: None of your examples can work because the first case (let array one) is expeting a result like if the operation was synchronous. However, it's asynchronous and it's actually returning **nothing**. The second case expects a **promise** returned, but none is returned. You should **return a Promise** instead and handle the result **asynchronously**.

Comment: I would expect that `return route.get().then( ... rest of code...` should work. Else there's something wrong with the route and specifically what `.resolve()` does to the result. Do you have docs about what exactly `.resolve()` will return? Is it part of Framework7 ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no return statement in getAllRestaurants. Try

```
export function getAllRestaurants(){
    //defining db route omitted
    let array = [];
    return route.get().then(function(querySnapshot){
```

and skip this line:

```
    .resolve(array)  //Have tried with only return and with only resolve
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you! I I seem to have misunderstood promises a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code to this:

```
export function getAllRestaurants(){
    // Return a new Promise, which will either resolve a value or reject an error.
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        //defining db route omitted
      let array = [];
      // Nothing changed here.
      route.get().then(function(querySnapshot){
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach(function(document){
              array.push(document.data());
          });
          resolve(array);
          // Replaced the below line with the one above.
          //return array; //Have tried with only return and with only resolve
      })
      // No need for the line below.
      // resolve(array)  //Have tried with only return and with only resolve
      .catch(function(error){
          console.error('error i firebase getallrestaurants: ', error);
          // Added a line here to reject the error.
          reject(error);
      });
    });
}
```

I've commented the edits above. In this way, you will always get a Promise out of that method, and you can use it in this way:

```
//importing my module
import * as database from './database';

database.getAllRestaurants().then(array =>{
  //do stuff
}).catch(err => {
   console.log('an error happened!');
});
```