# Return data from imported module which is Asynchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mongoose

I have read many articles relating my issue such as ([Returning a variable from a function in an imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55476302/returning-a-variable-from-a-function-in-an-imported-module) and [NodeJS can't returned data from imported module is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72801517/nodejs-cant-returned-data-from-imported-module-is-undefined))  I also read ([Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) and [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)) but im still stuck, I tried all the solutions by my issue is still persistent.

I am new to JS and am new to promises and await, which is mainly why I am confused.
I am using a simple mongoose function,

```
//Find and return user object function
async function findUser(associatedUser) {
  try {
    //Find a user based on given info
    const foundUser = await User.find({ associatedUser: associatedUser });
    //It returns a list of object, but usually its just one object. So we just get that one object
    const foundUserObject = foundUser.find(o => o.associatedUser == associatedUser);
    return foundUserObject;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}
```

The function finds a user based on their name and returns it, in the local file I can access the function return value like this

```
foundUserObject = await findUser(associatedUser);
```

and it works.

However when I import the module, and give an input

```
const MongoDBModule = require('./index');

MongoDBModule.findUser(associatedUserPrompt)
```

It always returns undefined, when I try to make my return a promise in the original code

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(FoundUserObject);
        }, 5000);
    });
```

which is what some links told me to do I still get undefined; I think its because im returning a static value and not a request but im not too sure

When I try to put the return in an async function I get this error ['await' has no effect on the type of this expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60368017/await-has-no-effect-on-the-type-of-this-expression)

and when I try to use

```
MongoDBModule.findUser(associatedUserPrompt).then(value => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Programming Related\MongooseTests\testingimport.js:18:45)  
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.14.0
```

From what I read this has something to do with a synchronous function trying to access an asynchronous return function, and I read many posts and tried everything but I'm really stuck. I just need to know how to not return undefined and return the object which I'm supposed to be getting.

This is what I'm supposed to get --

```
{
  associatedUser: '971567800902@c.us',
  currentContext: 'none',
  name: 'none',
  email: 'none',
  subject: 'none',
  budget: 'none',
  phone: 'none',
  message: 'none',
  mailinglist: false,
  _id: new ObjectId("63efda10621fb2247732d115"),
  __v: 0
}
```

How I export the function

```
module.exports = {
  findUserAndUpdateValues: function (associatedUser, givenObjectValue, newValue) {
    findUserAndUpdateValues(associatedUser, givenObjectValue, newValue);
  },

  createUser: function (associatedUser, currentContext, name, email, subject, budget, phone, message, mailinglist) {
    createUser(associatedUser, currentContext, name, email, subject, budget, phone, message, mailinglist);
  },

  findUser: function (associatedUser) {
    findUser(associatedUser);
  },
};
```

Comment: Please show how you export the  function

Comment: Ill edit the question and add it

Comment: You don't return anything from the exported function: `findUser: function (associatedUser) { findUser(associatedUser); }` should be `ifndUser: function (associatedUser) { return findUser(associatedUser); }`. It's just a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either add the missing `return`

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  findUser: function (associatedUser) {
    return findUser(associatedUser);
  },
};
```

Or don't create a wrapper function at all

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  findUser
};
```